# how to run test with ginkgo framwork in Go

Tags: go, automated-tests

I am Learning Go and try to understand basics of Go. I have written function and now i want to test function with predefined test cases.

[image]

here is code

> filename is arr_test.go

```
package arr_test

import (

    . "github.com/onsi/ginkgo"
    . "github.com/onsi/gomega"
    "github.com/manjeettahkur/r_project/arr"
    "testing"
)

func TestSo(t *testing.T) {
    RunSpecs(t, "My Test Suite")
}

var _ = Describe("Array", func() {
    Context("i have no idea why is going here", func() {
        It("should be like this", func() {
            Expect(arr.ArrayExm([]int{1, 2, 3, 4}, 10)).To(Equal([]int{1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1,1,2}))
        })
    })

})
```

> here is file where function is written  arr.go

```
package arr

func ArrayExm(array []int, limit int) []int {
    var res []int

    length := len(array)

    for i:=0; i < limit; i++ {

        if(i/length)%2 == 0{
            res = append(res,array[i%length])

        } else {
            res = append(res, array[length -i % length - 1])
        }
    }

    return res

}
```

when i run test case i receive this error

> Test Panicked
>       You are trying to make an assertion, but Gomega's fail handler is nil.
>       If you're using Ginkgo then you probably forgot to put your assertion in an It().
>       Alternatively, you may have forgotten to register a fail handler with RegisterFailHandler() or RegisterTestingT().

can anyone help what i am doing wrong here.TIA

Comment: Add `RegisterFailHandler(Fail)` above your `RunSpecs` call.  That tells Gomega to use Ginkgo's fail handler for failed assertions.

Comment: Also, for slices, it's generally better to use `ConsistOf` rather than `Equals`, unless the order of the slices is also an important quality of the slice.